# Why are negative enthalpies becoming more positive described as decreasing?

Tags: enthalpy

[This website](https://www.chemguide.co.uk/inorganic/group2/problems.html) and my lecturer have describe negative enthalpies that are becoming less exothermic as decreasing. A relevant diagram from the linked to website to illustrate what I mean:

[image]

I see the enthalpy of hydration is decreasing in magnitude but it is becoming more positive so why is it said to decrease? Is this a convention of some sort?

Comment: It is used this way because the values are closer to zero, i.e. the relative magnitude is smaller ignoring the sign because the signs are the same.  But it can be confusing: what if the hydration was +322, then one would have to say it had increased.

Comment: @porphyrin If I'm not mistaken, hydration enthalpies are always exothermic, right? Likewise for lattice formation enthalpy. And thank you for your comment, this makes more sense now.

Comment: I was just giving an example irrespective of being correct chemically :)